# file_get_contents(https://...@me): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, html, http, cookies

I am working on a webpage where I have to get data from an API (with PHP). The authenatication works fine and the user can log in. To save the access token I use the function setcookie() in php. However after some time the data dissapears and I get the following warning:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://...@me): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in C:\wamp\www\main.php on line 40
```

These are the lines:

```
function getUser($access_token){
$url = "https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.0/users/@me";

$opts = (array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer {$access_token}\r\n"
    )
));

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); //

$user = json_decode($response, true);
return $user['data'];
}
```

It's quite weird actually because it works when I delete the access token cookie and then log in (and authenticate) again... I simply do not understand why this is happening.

Setting the cookie (expires in is 31536000):

```
 if (!isset($_COOKIE['access_token'])) {
        setcookie('access_token', $data, time() + ($json['expires_in']));
    }
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your session expires?

Comment: I thought about that... but the access token is valid for 1 year

Comment: Where does the data disappear **from**? Look at your http traffic.

Comment: @symcbean As I am new to PHP: How can I look at my http traffic?

Comment: With a packet sniffer (e.g. wireshark) or a logging proxy (e.g. proxomitron, firebug, iehttpheaders)

Answer (score 0):

Check your expiry date of the cookie, even though the token may be valid on *your* side, the cookie may expire earlier.

Comment: I added the code at my question... can you please have a look at it?

Comment: Sorry, I removed my comment since I was not quite sure you were actually using jquery. Is the timing random? And have you checked how the cookie really looks like in a browser (what expiry data does it bear)?

Comment: The time() function is the actual system time. The expire date of the cookie is in 2016 (checked with EditThisCookie).

Comment: Based on your answer, I can only conclude that between the cookie, and doing the request, the token is stored in some local cache (php session?).

If true, and it is php's session, check your php session timeout.

Comment: The token is saved with $_COOKIE.. However I do use $_SESSION but that just for checking if the user is logged in/out

Comment: Can you do an api-call without being logged in, but with a valid token in your cookie? I am really suspecting your session timeout setting in php....

Comment: Well you basically do not really need to be logged in to make an api call if you already have the access token, yes.. alright.. I will try changing it.. however, how should I do it? There are like loads of possibilities on the internet..

Comment: First: @Symcbean has a good point/comment, second: I do not quite understand the exact question. Is your problem identified/solved/solvable? If you have another question, I guess you need to post a new one.

Since I don't have enough rep, I cannot move this discussion to a chat... feel free though!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Anyways, as I am new to PHP I do not really understand how I should look at my HTTP traffic.... and my question was how to change the session timeout settings; + I cannot move the discussion to a chat either (@Kasper Agg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe break it up a bit. Start at the simplest task, make it work. So, let's say you need an api call, make that call work. When that works, move on to the next step.

If the api call needs a secret token, I can imagine you don't want to just give it to any user to store it as a cookie.

Next step would be authentication. If you're not only new to PHP, but web applications in general, I would start with something less challenging.

But let's assume you'll master it quite soon, the next step (there is never a last step) could be a security decision: does the user need to do the api call, or can I do that for the user by doing the api call server side once the user is authorized?

Comment: Hmm, the thing is it is a school project and I do not have enough time to master it sadly but I do spend a lot of time trying to understand it very well. Good point with the security, however I do not know how else I should save the token. The problem is, if I do not save the token the user is always asked for accepting/declining certain scopes (data reading, updating, etc.) and I guess that is quite annoying for the user, that is why I saved it in a Cookie.

Comment: I think you could store it in a cookie, where and when do you store it? If you only store it after the user signs in, I would check your authenticated session. In other words: check your php configuration and try to increase your session timeout.